# SQL Server - Transaction is getting locked in case of error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, locking

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
    ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeLogs
    ADD SomeID NVARCHAR(250) NULL

    ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeLogs
    ADD SomeID NVARCHAR(250) NULL
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    DECLARE @Msg NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @Msg = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    RAISERROR('Error Occured: %s', 20, 101, @Msg) WITH LOG;
END CATCH;
```

Running the above query gives the following error which is correct as I am trying to add same column twice.

Msg 2705, Level 16, State 4, Line 6
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'SomeID' in table 'dbo.SomeLogs' is specified more than once.

**But the problem is that the SomeLogs table is locked. When I try to do SELECT on SomeLogs I get this error.**

---

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Lock request time out period exceeded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1222)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.3000&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=1222&LinkId=20476

---

**Why is the catch block not catching this error?** **And how to avoid table getting locked?**

Comment: do you have to add a new field everytime you run the script or this is only a one time script?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu - if i remove that field then there is no error and transaction won't be locked. But I am trying to simulate the scenario when there is an error and see whether it gets to CATCH or not. It doesn't.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu - Its a one time script but i want to make sure if there is an error for some unknown reason, it won't lock the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try..Catch
```

block will not catch this error because it's **compilation error**, and compilation errors cannot be catched within the **current scope**.
The table remains locked because locks are not released until transaction is committed or rolled back. When xact_abort is set to off(default for SSMS sessions) transaction is not rolled backed when the compilation error occurs, that is by (bad!) design, and to fix this you should use

```
set xact_abort on;
```

You can catch this error in outer scope, for example, if you wrap this code in stored procedure or dynamic code, executing sp/dynamic code within try..catch

Comment: Thanks for explaining why the error isn't caught in the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Using TRY…CATCH with XACT_STATE

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql

> The following example shows how to use the TRY…CATCH construct to
>   handle errors that occur inside a transaction. The XACT_STATE function
>   determines whether the transaction should be committed or rolled back.
>   In this example, SET XACT_ABORT is ON. This makes the transaction
>   uncommittable when the constraint violation error occurs.

Comment: because normally you don't do that code... the common issue would be data type mismatch and the rest but this is a difference case where a schema has been altered

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `SET XACT_ABORT ON` to automatically rollback the transaction in the event of an error or attention (i.e. client query cancel or timeout). The general `TRY/CATCH` pattern I suggest in stored procedures and batches in SQL 2012 and later:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;
    --do stuff
    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

See [Erland Sommarskog's error handling article](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the article.